# how to compare two columns in different data frames & replace the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Two dataframes are there,
df1 has 2 columns ,name & profession

```
df_1
        Name         profession     
        srinu        senior engineer    
        Azahar       engineer 
        vijaya       data analyst 
        rahul        team lead 
        swapna       manager
        krishna      engineer 
        rama         senior engineer
```

df_2 has only one column with (name-employeeid)
df_2

```
        Name-empid           
                
        vijaya-2124148      
        rahul-2124152    
        krishna-2124189     
        rama-2124169
```

I am trying to compare df1 and df2 using name and if names in df2 matches with df1, profession should be replaced as"data scientist".

i have tried many things,but couldn't figure it out,can someone help me,please?

i have tried using map,replace..but getting errors

Comment: Add the code snippets of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
# extract the names from df_2
m = (df_1['Name']
     .str.lower()
     .isin(df_2['Name-empid'].str.extract('(\w+)-', expand=False))
     )

# match with df_1 ensuring common case
df_1.loc[m, 'profession'] = 'Data Scientist'
```

Output:

```
      Name       profession
0    srinu  senior engineer
1   Azahar         engineer
2   vijaya   Data Scientist
3    rahul   Data Scientist
4   swapna          manager
5  krishna   Data Scientist
6     rama   Data Scientist
```

Comment: i have tried that, i am getting error  
     .TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: 1- please provide a reproducible input, 2- you must give full details of the error message and traceback

Comment: i have tried that, i am getting error .TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Ensure `df_1` is a DataFrame